# PowerBI RLS Manage Roles with Multi table

Tags: sql, powerbi, roles

PS THE TABLES CANT BE CHANGE
ITS OK TO ADD COLUMNS IN VIEW and Power Query and change like that.

[image]

I have explaned the problem in the image hope you guys can help me
I have tryed to make joins between the table Child and RLS1 RLS2 RLS3 but i can just use one.

My thought was to use this DAX (*I more specify use USERPRINCIPALNAME()*)

RLS1 = USERPRINCIPALNAME() ||

RLS2 = USERPRINCIPALNAME() ||

RLS3 = USERPRINCIPALNAME() ||

(
USERPRINCIPALNAME() = tblDimOverride'[Override]' && tblDimOverride'[Child]' = RLS1) ||

(
USERPRINCIPALNAME() = tblDimOverride'[Override]' && tblDimOverride'[Child]' = RLS2) ||

(
USERPRINCIPALNAME() = tblDimOverride'[Override]' && tblDimOverride'[Child]' = RLS3)

But i still think i need to join the table to be able to pull it off, and i cant do it becouse you can just link Child to ONE RLS and i need it like the SQL for them al three.
And i think that if i can link them i just need

RLS1 = USERPRINCIPALNAME() ||

RLS2 = USERPRINCIPALNAME() ||

RLS3 = USERPRINCIPALNAME() ||

USERPRINCIPALNAME() = tblDimOverride'[Override]'

**Add 20210920**

I was trying with some thing like this in "Handeling roles"

... || LOOKUPVALUE([RLS1],'tblDimOverride'[Child],userprincipalname())
And i need it for RLS1...RLS(n) so no link just between RLS1 and Child.

But then i get this error

**does not exist or has no relation to any table that is available in the current context**
but as explaned before i cant have a relation from child to RLS1.RLS2.RLS3...

**Added 20210929**

Did extra visualization, if i would go with a lookup (Cant solve it in PowerBI) and combine values into one column. And that dont look like a good solution eather.
So i think the solution from 20210920 would be the best but cant solve it

[image]

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to achieve here? Your explanation unfortunately is not very clear. The top line in the image states "...And Bud shall see the came". Do you mean see the same? If so, why is there a distinction between `God` and `Bud`? What does `RLS` mean? (Just to hopefully make it more understandable for outsiders who do not understand or know your business logic).

Comment: @SchmitzIT
Yes the language translation fix it wrong. came=same.RLS is Role Level security and can be found at START>Handel roles.The buisness logic and all nessessary is in the text.Bud is the chef over everyone and have midel management and workes. And god can even see buds rows. But now they want specific people to see like Peters workers. And this people are not over Peter in RLS. and its not smart to add a new RLS4 becouse more people can be added as exepletion from the organisation tree. So they need to be linked from another override table. How other people shall see Peters workers.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier if you reshape your tblDimMain into a [parent/child hierarchy](https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/alberto/2011/07/19/parent-child-hierarchies-in-tabular-with-denali/) table so that it looks like this:

[image: Table screenshot]

Once you have this, you can filter this table with a fairly simple condition:

```
PATHCONTAINS ( Main[Path], USERPRINCIPALNAME() )
    || PATHCONTAINS (
           Main[Path],
           LOOKUPVALUE ( Override[Child], Override[Override], USERPRINCIPALNAME() )
       )
```

Comment: Sorry but i cant change the main table its fixed with the RLS1.RLS2....n   the correct table is around 2800 rows of people. and this are alredy PowerBI connected to the structure thats now. and datawarehouse depending on it.  Its not a easy fix i have spent 2 week trying to solve it. But if you are able to help make a path in the main  from powerbi so i just need one column with multi value. that generated from the override table and combine with the RLS1.RLS2....n ... It looks like you are able to solve it but not quite there yet but im not able to take this and adapt it with your experties

Comment: For my suggested approach to work, you'll need a dimension table that has exactly one row for each person (whether under the [Name] column or in one of the RLS columns). I could help you reshape your table to achieve this in the query editor but it's too messy to write the logic with unique names scattered through multiple columns like your current table. I'm having a hard time envisioning how your `tblDimMain` relates to the rest of your model. What relationships does it have to other tables in your model?

Comment: OKi Then this is not the solution

Comment: In your solution can a person have two jobs in the same company? this is very common in a municipality. We say cleaner 50% and janitor 50%

Comment: Possibly. Where it really breaks down is if a person has more than one direct supervisor. This means the hierarchy is not a simple tree but a more complicated directed graph (which might even contain [cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_\(graph_theory\))).